# strange behavior chrome and html BASE tag

Tags: html, google-chrome

i have problem when i use html base tag in chrome. 
For Chrome is this ok

```
<base href="/" />
<base href="http://www.domain.com/" />
```

and this not

```
<base href="http://domain.com/" />
```

after submit form and page load, content of href attribute disappears.

```
<base href="" />
```

I tested it in Firefox and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

The `<base>` tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document.
The `<base>` tag **goes inside** the `<head>` element. In HTML the `<base>` tag has no end tag.
In XHTML the `<base>` tag must be properly closed (i.e. <`base />`).
Also note that the base URL must be an absolute URL!
The `href` attribute specifies a base URL for all relative URLs on a page, the `target` attribute specifies the default target for all hyper-links and forms in the page.

Comment: both relative and absolute are allowed. see MDN for reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
An example of usage is angular https://angular.io/guide/deployment